# setting the width of the grid view column to dynamic without compromising the minimum width for the control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, templatefield

I'm using

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  BorderWidth="0px" BorderColor="white" BorderStyle="Solid">

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tf1" ControlStyle-Width="40px">  
<ItemTemplate>    
<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:###,###,###,##0}",Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"tf1"))) %>' />
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tf1") %>'  style="display:none;text-align:right;" MaxLength = "9"  />  
</ItemTemplate>                                         
</asp:TemplateField> 

</asp:GridView>
```

The problem is eventhough the ConrolStyle-Width is set to 40 px, I want it to be dynamic in size to accomodate data which requires more than 40px space. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting ControlStyle-Width="40px" just set css class like this:

```
ControlStyle-CssClass="template"
```

and then style your fields as you want. You can add min-width which means all fields will have minimum width equal to specified and if content width is larger than field width will fit it content.

```
.template{
            min-width: 40px;
        }
```