# Set Gridview column minWidth

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we set minwidth of any particular column of a gridview?

I am not using itemtemplate or databound.

Can we do it in C# or any other way?

Comment: Presuming this is not RWD (in which case, you should be using a ListView), this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423075/setting-the-width-of-the-grid-view-column-to-dynamic-without-compromising-the-mi

Comment: you want to do in code behind ?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use CSS for this. First set the `ItemStyle-CssClass` to a specific class.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="minWidth">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("myColumn") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then define the minimum width for the column there

```
.minWidth {
    min-width: 400px;
}
```

If you only use autogenerated columns you can do this

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "min-width: 400px");
```

Comment: I am not using any templatefield or boundfield.

Comment: Updated my answer. It is possible but not recommended that. If you can switch to TemplateField.

Comment: I can't switch to the templatefield. Columns are generated dynamically.

Comment: to use  `<asp:TemplateField>` with auto generated field you can use `<asp:Label>` with `Bind` , see my answer

Answer (score 0):

For auto-generated fields , you can use `<asp:Label>` with `Bind` ,

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REQ_ID" SortExpression="REQ_ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="minWidth">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("REQ_ID")%>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

its `css`

```
    <style>

       .minWidth {
            min-width: 400px;
        }

    </style>
```